# How to combine several run configurations in IntelliJ together?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have an IntelliJ project with several modules. Some of the modules should be run as servers. For every server (module), I have a run configuration.

Can I bundle those run configurations together, so I don't need to click run or stop five times?

If it matters, the project is fully mavenized.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The previously accepted answer does not work for running multiple servers or any scripts which do not terminate. However, now you can use the `Compound` run configuration to execute multiple non-terminating servers simultaneously. It looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of what the setting looks like]

**Steps to get it working:**

1. Create the individual run configurations
2. Create a new compound configuration
3. Choose the desired individual run configurations.
4. Run the new `Compound` configuration.
5. [Go to the intellij documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/run-debug-configuration-compound.html).

All the individual configs will run simultaneously - perfect for servers and other threads which do not exit!

NOTE: Even the MultiRun plugin recommends using `Compound` on their [GitHub page](https://github.com/rkhmelyuk/multirun).
More info [in the IDEA documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/run-debug-configuration-compound.html).

Comment: is there a way of introducing a dependency or a delay ? I am trying to start several webservices but the second shouldnt start until the first has finished starting-up. The same with the third and fourth services they shouldnt start until the second and third have finished starting-up  respectively.

Comment: Yes it can be done however not through intellij. You have to write a script that first starts all the services in standby mode waiting for the "go" signal, then have it check somehow to see if the other service has finished, at which point it signals "go" to the next service. In nodejs I was able to do this exact thing by checking the filesystem to see if the manifest.json file was available, and if not, it checks every 2 seconds to see and when it finally finds it, continues the service.

Comment: yeah seems like a real nice thing for them to add. is there a new feature request opened on the github repo for this yet?

Answer (score 37):

## Update

This now is possible (despite the fact that the issues @CrazyCoder linked to are still open as of this date).  In Intellij 12, you can "Run Another Configuration" before launch when you're in "Edit Configurations".  Here's a screenshot:

[image: Run Another Configuration]

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.4 and this option simply dosent exist

Comment: @ThiagoBorn I'm using the same version and it does exist.

Comment: 12.1.4 and it is an option for me.

Comment: This doesn't work. IntelliJ waits for each run configurations to terminate before moving on to the next one. A no go for servers.

Comment: @AxelFontaine if your servers don't block the thread that creates them, it'll work fine.  So I guess this answer "potentially works".

Comment: @AxelFontaine I faced the same problem, but as Lodovik suggests below using Multirun plugin solves the issue.

Comment: Yes! Having just started trying IntelliJ, coming from Eclipse where this still can't be done, it's really great to have this feature. I typically want to build and then run java apps. One click, doing something else for a couple of minutes, then coming back to a running app is really nice.

Comment: I am not sure but I think there is a bug because intelliJ launches the configuration to be run before running that particular configuration but the original configuration is not run that is to be launched after launching the previous configuration. The compound configuration has the alphabetical list order issue

Answer (score 19):

Check out this [Multirun plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7248?pr=idea).

And yes, I found it following CrazyCoder's link, so props to him again!

Comment: Multirun plugin looks good. It allows to run multiple configuration in sequential order with delay. Unfortunately it doesn't allow to run specific configuration in debug mode

Answer (score 7):

I found that 'Compound' sorted all modules alphabetically and launched them in that order. This could be a problem if there are modules with dependencies. If there is a way to override that sorting, I could not find it.

Comment: They run all in parallel (i use Idea 2022)

Answer (score 1):

I am using the paid version of IntelliJ 2020.2

I wanted a simple thing - Start my Spring Boot application and then start my Angular application. I tried the 'Run Another Configuration' way and it did not work. I faced the same issue as faced by @AxelFontaine.

The Multirun plugin solved my problem. I did have to restart the IDE twice - once to update it after plugin installed and the second time because there was an error saving some configuration. But since then its working just as expected. This is very helpful as I can work on the UI and see the changes immediately and similarly the Spring dev tools lets me change code and it reloads immediately. This plugin is very very helpful.