# IntelliJ: Mapping running/debugging specific configurations to toolbar

Tags: intellij-idea

Googling, searching this site and random experimentation yielded nothing, so here goes.

I'm working on a project containing different Maven projects where several of them need to run in order for the system to work. (Clients, servers, etc.) Launching them all individually is kind of inconvenient, but as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604019/how-to-combine-several-run-configurations-in-intellij-together) suggests, there's no way to group them into a single configuration (nor does the situation seem to have changed since that answer).

Instead, I'm now wondering if it's possible to map running/debugging specific configurations to the toolbar, i.e. have a "Run Project 1" button, a "Debug Project 3-C" button, and so on instead of having to do the three-step process of opening the list, choosing a configuration and clicking run/debug for each needed component.

Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't have multiple configurations at the toolbar, but I can suggest a better alternative for running multiple configurations at once.

In IDEA 12 it's possible to run another configuration in the **Before launch** section. So you just add all the other configurations you want to be started with the current one in **Before launch** steps, then run single configuration and get all of them launched. Note that you can run Maven goals from the same configuration:

[image]

---

As you've noted, it will not work if the configuration continues to run as it will wait for the command to finish.

I'm afraid there is no easier way to do it right now except probably using the keyboard shortcut for the [run popup menu](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2009/10/invoking-rundebug-actions-in-intellij-idea-9/).

Here are the issues you should vote for:

- [IDEA-94341](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-94341) Launch Multiple "Run/Debug Configurations" At Once
- [IDEA-69968](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-69968) Add option to assign keyboard shortcut to Run/Debug configurations
- [IDEA-75078](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-75078) Make it possible to create toolbar action for running specific run configurations

Comment: Unfortunately, that will not work as the projects need to run in parallel, not sequentially. (Doing it the way you suggested will make it wait for the other configuration to end before starting the main one, which isn't really useful for a client-server situation.)