# Run WEB applications depending on another WEB application with single click in Intellij Idea

Tags: maven, web-applications, intellij-idea

I have Maven-based project, which has modules A and B, both packaged as WARs and interact only through REST interface.

Module B is GWT application by it's nature, and module A is plain REST app. So I can run B as regular GWT application in Intellij IDEA. But it's not clear how do I run application A *before* application B.

I can create 2 run configurations in IDEA and run applciation A and then application B, but that is ugly. So is it possible to start application A as dependency before running application B? And when B is stopped - then A is stopped as well?

Comment: It's not possible. See my [answer to the related question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15197687/104891).

Comment: so sad :( but thanks anyway

Comment: If those are two wars, why don't you deploy both artifacts in your run configuration? (in the `Deployment` tab)

Comment: it doesn't work for GWT, there's no way to deploy anything