# Is it possible to run multiple applications in IntelliJ with just one press of a button?

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a way to run multiple applications with just one press of a button?

Say, I have *AppA*, *AppB*, and *AppC* (they are all in java). Is there a way that they could run all 3 in some order with just one button press?

It's kinda tedious hitting the "run" button for like 10 applications. I'm assuming a script or maybe a plugin?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to combine several run configurations in Intellij together?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604019/how-to-combine-several-run-configurations-in-intellij-together)

Answer (score 167):

I think this has been possible since version 15. You simply create a Run/Debug Configuration of type 'Compound', and select the configurations you want to run, so:

0. Ensure you have previously set up run configurations for the various applications (or other run configurations) that you want to run.
1. Click on the 'Run' menu
2. Click 'Edit Configurations'
3. Click the green '+' icon (top-left of the window)
4. Click 'Compound'
5. In the right-hand pane, enter a meaningful name for your group, then click the green '+' icon (the one in the right-hand pane, not the top-left of the window)
6. Select one of the run configurations
7. Repeat 5 and 6 for all the configurations you want to run in a single click
8. Hit OK
9. Select your newly-created compound configuration in the drop-down in the menu bar
10. Hit the run button (note that you don't appear to be able start all the applications in debug mode, if you want to do that, you'll need to do so individually)
11. Watch all your applications start, one-by-one. Revel in your newly discovered free time

#### 2 drawbacks:

1. As CashIsClay points out below, you can't explicitly change the order that your configurations run in; they run in alphabetical order. I'm not sure that this is a big restriction though, I'd want my applications to be able to start in any order for resilience in production environments. Of course, a non-terrible workaround would be to name your run configurations something like: '1. Foo'; '2. Bar', if it's essential for Foo to run before Bar starts.
2. You can only start in 'run' mode, not 'debug'.

Other answers have mentioned the Multirun plugin, which may offer more functionality than IntelliJ's native options. I haven't used it, but it might be worth looking at.

Comment: This unfortunately does not allow you to set the order at all. A better option is the Multirun plugin suggested by @user1338062

Comment: In order to set the order (no pun intended), just use the "Before launch" section to set prerequisites for a task. I found it useful to compile TS before running JS

Comment: Actually @DaveyDaveDave's approach only run multip configuration in parallel, no order could be specified

Comment: It's now possible to use debug mode with this

Answer (score 34):

There seems to be a [Multirun plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7248) for IDEA:

> Allows to run multiple run configurations at once: group multiple run
>   configurations and start them in a single click. Not only application
>   and test run configurations can be grouped, but other Multirun
>   configurations can be organized into single run configuration.

Comment: What is more current version (IDEA 2016.2.5) of 'Compound' doesn't support running all the configuration in debug mode, comparing to the Multirun plugin that hasn't got any problems with that.

Comment: It's 2018 and this is still the best solution. It's a shame IDEA still doesn't support this by default.

Comment: Yes with multirun you can configure maven configurations(for eg) and then hook them up using the "Before Launch" option in the individual maven configuration to maintain an execution order.

Answer (score 29):

You can do this. Go to `Run` -> `Edit Configurations...`.

Older IntelliJ versions:
Check `Allow parallel run`, then you can start multiple main classes.

IntelliJ 2020+:
Select `Modify options`. A popup appears. Enable `Allow multiple instances`.

Comment: This is not an answer for the question

Comment: True, but most people will search for this :D.

Answer (score 15):

You can agroup the projects, go to "Edit Configurations..."

[image]

The following screen will open, under "Application" configure your settings

[image]

Once you create a "Compound"

[image]

And put "Compound" your settings

[image]

Done, just run the "Compound"

[image]

Answer (score 8):

There is no such feature yet, please vote:

- [IDEA-94341](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-94341) Launch Multiple "Run/Debug Configurations" At Once

Comment: I see.. thanks. I will definitely vote for it. I hope they implement it on future releases. :D

Answer (score 0):

with Pycharm version 2023.2.1 you can do it by services
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vs5M1.png)

Answer (score -2):

Edit run configuration, check the *allow run parallel* checkbox.

Answer (score -5):

Select the Written program(java/Scala) --> right click --> Edit --> Select Allow parallel runs check box[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BG8Ww.png)

Comment: OP asks if there is a way to run multiple programs with one click of the run button, not if he can run the same binary in parallel.