# How to run multiple build configurations at once in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, buildconfiguration

I have a project that has a "standard user" and "manager" build configurations. (The code is mostly same but some aspects of the build are different.)

When I'm about to test the application, I need to start both configurations, user and manager. Currently, I do that manually but isn't there a way to start both configurations automatically together?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to combine several run configurations in Intellij together?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604019/how-to-combine-several-run-configurations-in-intellij-together)

Answer (score 1):

You can let one of the configurations start the other one:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, my build configurations are AIR desktop apps and for example if I attempt to start the "manager" configuration from the "user" one, it waits until the "manager" app is closed before the "user" is run. It doesn't start them side by side.

Comment: Afaik, it's not possible.