# How to run configurations one after another in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm trying to create a compound/multirun run configuration in intellij where each configuration runs sequentially.  I've tried with both compound and multirun, however it appears that neither allow configurations to be run one after the other (as in the second waits for the first to finish).

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to combine several run configurations in Intellij together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604019/how-to-combine-several-run-configurations-in-intellij-together)

Answer (score 4):

There are related requests for Compound configuration: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-166035 and for Multirun plugin: https://github.com/rkhmelyuk/multirun/issues/63

Comment: Thanks, one of those is my request :P

Answer (score 4):

This is possible by using the plain `Before Launch` settings of a Run Configuration. There you can specify one or more other Run Configurations. These will run sequentially before running the original Run Configuration.

Comment: The problem is that I need to run something after.  There is no option to run something after, so I was going to have 2 configs, one for before/main action, and one for the after action, but this doesn't work because there doesn't seem to be any way to run configurations in sequence.

Comment: you should run the config that you want to run as last, and configure the run config that has to run prior to it in the before launch tasks. For example, you have 3 run configs: A, B and C. You want to run A first, followed by B and finish with C as last. You configure C to have B as before launch, and you configure B to have A as before launch. Then you run C and it will run A and B first for you. (not sure if you can combine A+B)